# replacing float 0 with NaN

Tags: python

I want to replace a float64 variable with NaN when it has a value of zero (it does not have a value of zero all the time). I tried using

```
df["Temp"].replace(0.,np.nan)
```

but it didn't have any affect. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you using `pandas`?

Comment: Does it return you a new dataframe that you want? Or I guess you may set inplace=True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alternatively try:

```
df.loc[df['temp']==0, 'temp'] = np.nan
```